# How is interpolation used in the proof of Lemma 4.1 in Tao's article Endpoint Strichartz Estimates?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, interpolation

In the proof of Lemma 4.1, pp. 962–963 in "Endpoint Strichartz Estimates" by Tao and Keel (1997) (see [MR1646048](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1646048) or [Zbl 0922.35028](https://zbmath.org/0922.35028)), the authors first proved the statements hold for some boundary and vertex values of $(a,b)$, and then it was claimed that the statements of the Lemma hold true for points in some neighborhood of $(r,r)$ since $(r,r)$ is in the convex hull determined by those boundary and vertex values of $(a,b)$. This is due to interpolation for bilinear forms, according to the expression in the article.

**Question**. I wonder what is interpolation for bilinear forms and how it is used here. Is there some books including this? I merely heard of interpolation for operators between function spaces, and interpolation for functionals of single variable as well. But never saw interpolation for bilinear forms before...

[image: The lemma in question, and its proof, is shown in this screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Keel-Tao implicitly used two multilinear interpolation results.

#### Three end point multilinear interpolation

For general Banach spaces this is given as Exercise 3.13.5b in

*Bergh, Jöran; Löfström, Jörgen*, [**Interpolation spaces. An introduction**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/334838), Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften. 223. Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. X, 207 p. with 5 figs. DM 60.00; $ 24.60 (1976). [ZBL0344.46071](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0344.46071).

In the case used for Strichartz estimates, the function spaces involved are (vector valued) $L^p$ spaces, and a complete proof is given in

*O’Neil, Richard*, [**Convolution operators and L(p, q) spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-63-03015-1), Duke Math. J. 30, 129-142 (1963). [ZBL0178.47701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0178.47701).

The statement of the Theorem is:

> **Thm** Let $A_0, A_1, B_0, B_1, C_0, C_1$ be Banach spaces. Let $T$ be a bilinear mapping with the following bounds:
> $$ \begin{align*}
> \| T(a,b) \|_{C_0} &\lesssim \|a\|_{A_0} \|b\|_{B_0} & (T:&A_0\times B_0 \to C_0) \\
> \| T(a,b) \|_{C_1} &\lesssim \|a\|_{A_0} \|b\|_{B_1} & (T:&A_0\times B_1 \to C_1) \\
> \| T(a,b) \|_{C_1} &\lesssim \|a\|_{A_1} \|b\|_{B_0} & (T:&A_1\times B_0 \to C_1) \end{align*} $$
> then for $\theta, \theta_A, \theta_B \in (0,1)$ with $\theta = \theta_A + \theta_B$, and $p,q,r\in [1,\infty]$ with $1 \leq \frac1p + \frac1q$, we have
> $$ \|T(a,b)\|_{C_{\theta,r}} \lesssim \|a\|_{A_{\theta_A,pr}} \|b\|_{B_{\theta_B,qr}} \quad (T: A_{\theta_A,pr} \times B_{\theta_B,qr} \to C_{\theta, r}) $$
> here for $X \in \{A,B,C\}$, the space $X_{\theta,r}$ is the real interpolation space $(X_0,X_1)_{\theta,r}$.

#### Two end point multilinear interpolation

For general Banach spaces this is proven as Theorem 4.4.1 in Bergh and Lofstrom. It states

> **Thm** Let $A_0, A_1, B_0, B_1, C_0, C_1$ be Banach spaces. Let $T$ be a bilinear mapping with the following bounds:
> $$ \begin{align*}
> \| T(a,b) \|_{C_0} &\lesssim \|a\|_{A_0} \|b\|_{B_0} & (T:&A_0\times B_0 \to C_0) \\
> \| T(a,b) \|_{C_1} &\lesssim \|a\|_{A_1} \|b\|_{B_1} & (T:&A_1\times B_1 \to C_1) \end{align*} $$
> then for $\theta \in (0,1)$, we have
> $$ \|T(a,b)\|_{C_{[\theta]}} \lesssim \|a\|_{A_{[\theta]}} \|b\|_{B_{[\theta]}} \quad (T: A_{[\theta]} \times B_{[\theta]} \to C_{[\theta]}) $$
> here for $X \in \{A,B,C\}$, the space $X_{[\theta]}$ is the complex interpolation space $(X_0,X_1)_{[\theta]}$.

---

The details of how they are applied for the proof of the Strichartz estimate is too long to include in an MO answer. I wrote up a version as Theorem 4.88 in [my lecture notes](https://qnlw.info/course-notes/dispersive_notes/dispersive_notes.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps.